# What is the equivalent of Android's RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-listview

Android gives scroll states like `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` which tells when user stops the scroll. I'm not able to find any **alternative** in flutter for `Pageview` or `ListView` ScrollListener.

#### My Problem

I need to detect scroll up/down in PageView to perform some operation based on that. Flutter gives the direction (`_myPageViewController.position.userScrollDirection`) but it gives a continuous callback. I need to detect it only when the user stops scrolling.

#### Another scenario

I need to do auto-play videos in a listView. So I need to detect when the user stops scrolling and then get the position and play that.

In android I would have done this with the help `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` state in `RecyclerView's` scrollListener. Need something similar in flutter.

Comment: see `ScrollEndNotification` class documentation

Comment: this is a great post https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) and [@doc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5522344/doc) `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>` gives the callback of scroll start, scroll end.

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
    if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
      print("Scroll End"); //Scroll end callback
     }
    return false;
    },
  child: ListView.builder(
      //...
      ),
)
```

This also works with other scrollable widgets like `PageView`.