# How to detect if the user started scrolling the Listview.builder vertically?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I'm trying to hide a container if the user started scrolling so that it would give more space and visibility to the listview. I tried Gesturedetector as the parent of the Listview.builer and used its "onVerticalDragStart" but no luck on that one. I'm a beginner in flutter, I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: To detect only scroll start you can check `NotificationListener`. [Check this if it helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57249562/4768512)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`ScrollController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html), but [@Sp4Rx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4768512) proposed a better solution: [`NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html)

You simply wrap your `ListView.builder` in a `NotificationListener` with generic type `ScrollNotification` to handle [`ScrollNotification`s](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollNotification-class.html) sent by scrolling your `ListView`:

```dart
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
    if (notification is ScrollStartNotification) {
      // Handle your desired action on scroll start here.
    }

    // Returning null (or false) to
    // "allow the notification to continue to be dispatched to further ancestors".
    return null;
  },
  child: ListView.builder(...),
)
```

You can look at the documentation for [`ScrollStartNotification` here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollStartNotification-class.html).

Comment: Thanks! I've read the documentation and finally understand its use. thanks!